# Visual Studio 2015 error when multiple debug: The process cannot access the file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have 2 projects in solution (2 WPF apps: Client and Server). When i debug each project separately then everything is ok. When i debug both projects after build solution then ok again. 
Error appears when i build solution, make change in code of Client project, then start debug only Server project and while debugging i start debug Client project. So when i start second debug Visual Studio shows me error "The process cannot access the file '\obj\Debug\Otb.Client.exe' because it is being used by another process.". Can i do this without error?

Answer (score 1):

1) Open the "Tools" menu, and click "Options".

2) Expand "Projects and Solutions".

3) Click on "Build and Run" tab.

4) Uncheck "Only build startup projects and dependencies to Run"